# Typo in "Stack Overflow Thanks YOU!" page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, spelling

As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/10m), highlighted in yellow color:

> [image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's intentional, and this should have been posted on Meta SO.

Comment: I think you highlighted too little. though, at that point you might have realized it was on purpose. :)

Comment: I tagged it as BUG ..nothing seems mean. bug is bug ..

Comment: What you see as a bug, is a feature. ;)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ not sure bug report should end with a question mark. It's a report about something that is broken, not request for support. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok... :( removed. *runs and hides*

Answer (score 9):

Clearly it's intentional, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

"teh twitters" wouldn't even be correct as "the twitter", as "twitter" itself should be spelled "Twitter" since it's a registered trademark.

Feel free to read it like this:

> Not on Twitter? No problem. Just add #SOReadyToHelp to your "About Me" on your profile page.

Just as you would read "gimmeh-teh-codez" questions as "give me the code".